# How to manage patient preferences (multi-slots request) for appointments in database?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

What is the best way to manage preferences for appointments in database? In my scenario a patient can send multiple preferences (slots) for appointments to a practitioner. The practitioner will approve the most feasible slot according to his/her availability.

How can I design a ERD so that I can allow different no. of preferences to different patients, e.g. patient A can send only 2 preferences based upon its pricing plan and patient B can send 5 preferences based upon its pricing plan.

[image]

Comment: Isn't `preferences` an `integer` which limits the number of preferences (future unconfirmed appointments)? However I would probably move it to a `plan` table so it is stored per plan, not per appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need a pivot table. It would need to have patient_id, practitioner_id, and preferred_time. The patient would create records in this table. When a practitioner approved a preferred_time, the data could be copied into this appointment table you are showing and expanded.

You can then add a hasMany preferred_time relationship to the patient model, and use that to interact with the data.

Any combination of patient and practitioner could have zero, one, or many preferred times at any given time.